# Angular js text angular component event on key up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, textangular

I'm using text-angular component in my client side and have a problem with adjusting the view. Everything works great except for when I press a keyboard button and hold it for a while. When I do that the text adjusts badly - the text angular and the entire window along width grows outside of the window.

I had that problem also when copy pasting without dropping the keyboard. I managed to fix this problem by changing the source code of text-angular in an ugly way - by manually adding a white space in the copied text inside the proccesPaste function.

What happens is that a

tag is created and the entire long text inside of it. This

tag causes the window stretch

Please help me figure this one out. How can I handle a long nonestop typing without having the window grows insanly huge?

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redesigning my html. What caused the problem was that the text-angular was inside of a table. After I put it outside of the table in it's own div everything worked as expected.